# http request took too long time

Tags: c#, httprequest, httpclient

I trying to get data from a server with HttpClient Object in c#. I have an HttpRequest class to send my http requests. here is my function in HttpRequest class :

```
public CML.Candle GetCandles(CML.Coins Coin, int candleCount, string timeFrame)
    {
        HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        clientHandler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        clientHandler.Properties.Add("Accept-Encoding", "br, gzip, deflate");
        clientHandler.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

        _client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);

        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml");
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "just test app");
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");

        CML.Candle candles = new CML.Candle();
        CandleResponse candleResponse = new CandleResponse();
        int tmpCandlesCount = candleCount;
        int step = 1500;
        do
        {
            if (candleCount > 0)
            {
                if (tmpCandlesCount > step)
                    tmpCandlesCount -= step;
                else
                    step = tmpCandlesCount;
            }

            string queryString = GetQueryString(Coin.symbol, step, candleCount, timeFrame);

            URI = _serverApi.GetCandlesRoute(queryString);
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            response = _client.GetAsync(URI).Result;

            string jsonData = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            candleResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CandleResponse>(jsonData);

            candles = (Convert2Candle(candleResponse.data, Coin));
        } while (candleResponse.data.Count == 1500);


        return candles;
    }
```

And I call this function like this :

```
void ProcessData(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            _isInProccess = true;
            ExKu.HttpRequests requests = new ExKu.HttpRequests();
            CML.CandleQueryInfo queryInfo = (CML.CandleQueryInfo)obj;
            CML.Candle candle = new CML.Candle();
            CML.CandleOpration opration = new CML.CandleOpration();
            List<CML.Coins> coins = _coins.Where(x => x.enableTrading = true && x.quoteCurrency == _selectedMarket).OrderBy(x => x.symbol).ToList(); //&& x.symbol == "BTC-USDT"

            foreach (var coin in coins)
            {
                _canceltoken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                _symbol = coin.symbol;
                
                
                candle = requests.GetCandles(coin, queryInfo.candleCount, queryInfo.timeFrame);
                

                if (candle != null && candle.Candles.Count >= (queryInfo.candleCount * 0.80))
                {

                    Task MA20 = new Task(() =>
                    {
                        candle.Candles = opration.CalculateMovingAverage(candle.Candles, 20);
                    });


                    Task MA50 = new Task(() =>
                    {
                        candle.Candles = opration.CalculateMovingAverage(candle.Candles, 50);
                    });

                    Task MA100 = new Task(() =>
                    {
                        candle.Candles = opration.CalculateMovingAverage(candle.Candles, 100);
                    });

                    Task MA200 = new Task(() =>
                    {
                        candle.Candles = opration.CalculateMovingAverage(candle.Candles, 200);
                    });

                    MA20.Start();
                    MA50.Start();
                    MA100.Start();
                    MA200.Start();

                    Task.WaitAll(MA20, MA50, MA100, MA200);

                    Task RSI = new Task(() =>
                    {
                        candle.Candles = opration.CalculateRSI(candle.Candles, 14);
                    });

                    Task CCI = new Task(() =>
                    {
                        candle.Candles = opration.CalculateCCI(candle.Candles, 20);
                    });

                    Task ichimoku = new Task(() =>
                    {
                        candle.Candles = opration.CalculateIchimoku(candle.Candles);
                    });

                    Task MACD = new Task(() =>
                    {
                        candle.Candles = opration.CalcMACD(candle.Candles);
                    });


                    RSI.Start();
                    CCI.Start();
                    ichimoku.Start();
                    MACD.Start();
                    Task.WaitAll(RSI, CCI, ichimoku, MACD);

                    Task bollingerband = new Task(() =>
                    {
                        candle.Candles = opration.CalculateBollingerBand(candle.Candles, 20, 1);
                    });

                    bollingerband.Start();
                    Task.WaitAll(bollingerband);

                    _candles.Add(candle);
                }

                var delFinish = new FinishProcData(FinishProcess);
                dataGridView1.Dispatcher.Invoke(delFinish, candle, 0);
            }

            var endProc = new FinishProcData(FinishProcess);
            dataGridView1.Dispatcher.Invoke(endProc, candle, 1);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var error = new ShowError(DisplayException);
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(error, ex, "ProcessData");
        }
    }
```

Now I have a problem that is when I run my project in my PC (client system) everything is alright and receive data less than a second but in an other PC (an other client) http response took too long time and receive data more than normal state (in range 5 seconds to 5 minutes).
Is it depends on system hardware?

Comment: It can depend on a lot of things: hardware, network setup, DNS, etc. It's really hard for us to guess what might be different between the environment where it's fast and the one where it's slow. But be careful about creating new HttpClients and new HttpClientHandlers: that can cause socket contention. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient-guidelines

Comment: So how can I set specific DNS in my http request for test?

Comment: Probably you are just hammering the server. But there are a lot of issues with your code: use `await` not `.Result` **always**, and use `await Task.WhenAll` not `Task.WaitAll`. Pass the cancellation token everywhere you can. Create the `HttpClient` and handler only once, and put it into a static field. `clientHandler.Properties.Add("Accept-Encoding", "br, gzip, deflate");` is wrong and should be deleted, as you are not accepting `br` and any case the handler will add that. `x.enableTrading = true` should be `x.enableTrading == true` or just `x.enableTrading`.

Comment: @Charlieface thanks for your attention. I fixed my mistakes as you said  but my problems already exist and nothing changed.